# Mondoid search one document with multiples in a has_many/belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid

I have this releationship

```
class Cupboard
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :name, type: String
 has_many :ingredients 
end

class Recipe
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :name, type: String
 has_many :ingredients
end

class Ingredient
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :name, type: String
 field :description, type: String
 belongs_to :cupboard
 belongs_to :recipe
end
```

I need to create a method in Cupboard model to find a recipe that contains the same ingredients as the cupboard, I don't find in the Mongoid docs a method to find it.

I need something like `Recipe.find( #all cupboard.ingredients.ids )`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def shared_recipes
  ingredients.map(&:recipe).uniq
end
```